# How to write Android service in C++

Tags: android, c++, android-service, android-source, aidl

I have Google source code and want to write one [Android Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) in lower layer similar to how Android provides for App and Frameworks layer.

Is it possible?

If yes, I want to access this native service in my app though IMyService.Stub.asInterface.

Obviously my that service should be be running in different process and services to be provided by my native service should expose [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can.
First you must define you own protocol, like the message definitions.
Then you implement your server side, register it with service manager, and waiting for the binder calls.
Your client could get the service handle from the service manager and then send binder call to the server.

You can refer to the media_server and mediaplayer source code in AOSP.

Comment: Through this, I want to avoid JNI call. I will try this and update here.